# ts_rank massively slows my query, how can I improve performance?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Here's the table definition

```
Table "public.kb_article_contents"
   Column   |   Type   | Modifiers 
------------+----------+-----------
article_id | smallint | not null
contents   | text     | not null
keywords   | text     | not null
Indexes:
   "contents_idx" gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, contents))
Foreign-key constraints:
   "kb_article_contents_article_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES kb_articles(id)
```

and the query

```
support=> EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT
    id,
-- if we remove the next line runtimes speeds up (and of course the order by)
    ts_rank(to_tsvector( 'english', contents ), plainto_tsquery('string')) AS rank
FROM
    kb_article_contents
    INNER JOIN kb_articles
            ON ( kb_article_contents.article_id = kb_articles.id )

WHERE
    published = 'true'
    AND
    to_tsvector( 'english', contents ) @@ plainto_tsquery('string')
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 25
;
```

Here's the query plan for the slow query

```
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=57.90..57.92 rows=5 width=830) (actual time=452.003..452.028 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=57.90..57.92 rows=5 width=830) (actual time=452.001..452.010 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (ts_rank(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, kb_article_contents.contents), plainto_tsquery('string'::text)))
         Sort Method:  top-N heapsort  Memory: 17kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=21.36..57.85 rows=5 width=830) (actual time=17.688..451.334 rows=299 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (kb_articles.id = kb_article_contents.article_id)
               ->  Seq Scan on kb_articles  (cost=0.00..32.06 rows=1156 width=4) (actual time=0.008..1.059 rows=1156 loops=1)
                 Filter: published
               ->  Hash  (cost=21.30..21.30 rows=5 width=828) (actual time=1.175..1.175 rows=302 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 279kB
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on kb_article_contents  (cost=4.30..21.30 rows=5 width=828) (actual time=0.318..0.700 rows=302 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, contents) @@ plainto_tsquery('string'::text))
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on contents_idx  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.284..0.284 rows=302 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, contents) @@ plainto_tsquery('string'::text))
Total runtime: 452.109 ms
(15 rows)
```

Here's the query plan without the `ts_rank`

```
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=21.36..57.81 rows=5 width=4) (actual time=0.812..0.938 rows=25 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=21.36..57.81 rows=5 width=4) (actual time=0.810..0.920 rows=25 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (kb_articles.id = kb_article_contents.article_id)
        ->  Seq Scan on kb_articles  (cost=0.00..32.06 rows=1156 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.064 rows=89 loops=1)
           Filter: published
        ->  Hash  (cost=21.30..21.30 rows=5 width=2) (actual time=0.782..0.782 rows=302 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 7kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on kb_article_contents  (cost=4.30..21.30 rows=5 width=2) (actual time=0.203..0.589 rows=302 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, contents) @@ plainto_tsquery('string'::text))
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on contents_idx  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.171..0.171 rows=302 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, contents) @@ plainto_tsquery('string'::text))
Total runtime: 1.002 ms
(12 rows)
```

I'm not sure why adding `ts_rank` to the query is causing it to balloon in time like this. Is there anything I can do to optimize the query? please note that removing the `ORDER BY` does not increase the speed of the query, so it doesn't appear to be that.

Answer (score 3):

`ts_rank` will rank all rows, most of which will probably have a ranking of 0. So it's faster to do a search without `ts_rank` and then `ts_rank` the results of that search using the same query. So you'd probably want to do something like

```
SELECT score.id, ts_rank(score.contents::tsvector, plainto_tsquery('string')) as rank from
(SELECT
    id, contents
FROM
    kb_article_contents
    INNER JOIN kb_articles
            ON ( kb_article_contents.article_id = kb_articles.id )

WHERE
    published = 'true'
    AND
    contents::tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('string')) 
    as score
order by rank desc;
```

Comment: Is this really the case ? won't ts_rank only be applied to the records that are in the where condition already ?

Answer (score 2):

You have three function calls which are likely fairly CPU intensive.  `to_tsvector( 'english', contents )` will need to be run for each row and is likely where your time is spent.  `plainto_tsquery('string')` should be run only once per query so it shouldn't cost that much.  `ts_rank` will also need to be run for each row no matter how you do your data.

Rather than generate the tsvector each query you should create a text search index.  See the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-tables.html) for details.

Comment: I created an index, it's using it, that's what the "contents_idx". If I didn't have even without using `ts_rank` it would take like 10s to run. Perhaps it's not using it as much as it could be? any idea whether I can get more out of it?

Comment: ts_rank is documented to be I/O intensive so more memory may help caching.  On Linux/Unix you could try running `sar` while the query is running to determine where the bottleneck is.